# Connect to server with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, cookies, connection

I try connect to server and get data using jQuery. The server asks for a username and password, but I can not find how it is transmitted. After sending the username and password I receive in response to a cookie, which I have to make to the next question.

Screen from Fiddler the better show what's going on:

When I type the address in the browser:
[image]

Cookies is empty, browser display login panel:
[image]

When I write login, password and click Ok, two requests are sent with cookies:
[image]
[image]


How connect this server in js or jquery? 
Think I need to somehow send a username and password, retrieve cookies and then execute another query with the coockie.
Please, any advice, because google will not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is using HTTP Authorization to display a restricted page. There are several types of Authorizations, simplest one is [HTTP Basic Authorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). In this HTTP Basic Authorization , once user enters the username and password in the displayed login box, [base64 encoded value](https://www.base64encode.org/) (not encrypted !!!) of 'username:password' will be sent to server in "Authorization" HTTP header.

```
Authorization: Basic dGVzdHVzZXI6dGVzdHBhc3N3b3Jk
```

Please see live example (#10) [here](http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/)

But in your case, the server is using [NTLM HTTP Authorization](http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html), which involves 4-way handshake. I’m not sure, but it should be complicated to complete these steps with javascript.

I strongly recommend you to use JMETER  for this task. JMETER offers [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager), that should solve your problem easily. Also, JMETER offers many other features for handling Client-side HTTP tasks.

Good Luck!